# Fused Location Provider class not found despite Google Play Services dependency in gradle file

Tags: android, google-play-services, fusedlocationproviderapi

My app uses the `FusedLocationProviderApi` for getting the current location. I've already put the line which allows the app to use Google Play Services in the gradle file for my app module:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.2'
```

But when I try to declare a `FusedLocationProvider` variable, it turns red and does not recognize the class. My only guess is that I should probably import the class, but I don't know exactly how.

Answer (score 10):

You are currently only importing the ads API.

In addition to the ads compile line, you will need to add this to your build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
```

To see the current breakdown of individual APIs, take a look at the documentation: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: Thank you very much Daniel - it worked :) I am very new to android studio- will remember for next time.